# How to plot a standard density curve using plotly?

Tags: python, plotly

How to plot a density curve in python using plotly?

Specifically, I would like to do that for some standard densities.

---

UPDATE:

So far, the best way of achieving what I ask for (in a Jupyter notebook):

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats

import plotly.graph_objs as go
from plotly.offline import init_notebook_mode, iplot
init_notebook_mode(connected=True)
```

**Plotting**

```
xrange = np.arange(-4.5,5,0.0025)
norm = go.Scatter(x=xrange, 
                  y=stats.norm(loc=0, scale=1).pdf(xrange), 
                  mode='lines',
                  line=dict(width=1.5),
                  name='Normal',
                 )
lognorm = go.Scatter(x=xrange[xrange>0], 
                     y=stats.lognorm(s=1, loc=0, scale=1).pdf(xrange[xrange>0]), 
                     mode='lines',
                     line=dict(width=1.5),
                     name='Lognormal',
                    )
cauchy = go.Scatter(x=xrange, 
                     y=stats.cauchy(loc=0, scale=1).pdf(xrange), 
                     mode='lines',
                     line=dict(width=1.5),
                     name='Cauchy',
                    )
data = [norm, lognorm, cauchy]
iplot(data, show_link=False)
```

[image]

---

I was looking for an easy, parsimonious way, as it is done in *Mathematica* for instance:

```
Plot[{PDF[NormalDistribution[], x], PDF[LogNormalDistribution[0, 1], x], PDF[CauchyDistribution[], x]}, {x, -4.5, 4.5}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The code below uses [`gaussian_kde`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.gaussian_kde.html). The plots are in `iplot()`, `plotly`, as well as `matplotlib`, and [`seaborn`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/distributions.html) to compare them together. (`Jupyter Notebook 5.0.0`, `Python 3.6.6`)

```
# Import libraries
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from numpy import linspace
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import scipy.stats as st
from scipy.stats.kde import gaussian_kde

import plotly.offline as pyo
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from plotly import __version__
%matplotlib inline

import cufflinks as cf
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode, plot, iplot 
init_notebook_mode(connected=True)

init_notebook_mode(connected=True)
cf.go_offline()
```

**Create sample data**

```
np.random.seed(1)
data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(500,1), columns=['x'])
data.head(2)
```

**Calculate `kde` values and put them in a dataframe**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x_range': linspace(min(data['x']), max(data['x']), len(data['x'])),
                     'x_kde': kde(x_range) 
                    })
```

**Use `iplot()` to create plot**

```
df.iplot(x='x_range', y='x_kde')
```

[image]

**Use `plotly` to create plots**
Note: This plot opens in a new browser window

```
# Create trace, data and layout 
trace = go.Scatter(x=df['x_range'],y=df['x_kde'], mode='markers',name='markers')
data = [trace]
layout = go.Layout(title='Line Chart')
# Plot figure
fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
pyo.offline.plot(fig)
```

[image]

**Use `Seaborn` to plot**

```
sns.distplot(data['x'], hist=False, rug=True)
```

[image]

**Use base `plot`**

```
data['x'].plot.density()
```

[image]

**Use `Matplotlib` to plot**

```
kde = gaussian_kde(data.x)
x_range = linspace(min(data.x), max(data.x), len(data.x))
plt.plot(x_range, kde(x_range) )
```

[image]

**Edit** . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .

One approach would be to compile all values in a `dataframe` and then send it to `iplot()` in one line.

*Create dataframe*

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'xrange':np.arange(-4.5,5,0.0025)})
df['norm_x'] = stats.norm(loc=0, scale=1).pdf(df['xrange'])
df['cauchy_x'] = stats.cauchy(loc=0, scale=1).pdf(df['xrange'])
df['lognormal_x'] = stats.lognorm(s=1, loc=0, scale=1).pdf(df['xrange'])
df = pd.DataFrame({'xrange':xrange, 'norm_x':norm_x, 'cauchy_x':cauchy_x, 'lognormal_x':lognormal_x})
```

*Plot using `iplot()`*

```
df.iplot(x='xrange', y=['norm_x', 'cauchy_x', 'lognormal_x'])
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Useful, but not really what I've asked for. See my update.

Comment: Thank you for the description. I understand now. I've updated the post by trying to come close to a oneline approach to plot.